# Multiples downloads works in web but no in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, web, mobile

I'm trying to download multiples images from the server. On the web this works fine, but when I try to download in mobile this only downloads a single file. Why this occurs?
The code that I use to download the files:

```
async downloadAllImages() {
                this.allImages = this.cotacao[0].imagem.split(';');

                'use strict';

                const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, ms));

                for (var i = 0; i < this.allImages.length; i++) {
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.download = null;
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    a.href = `https://api.com/?imagem=${this.allImages[i]}`;
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.append(a);
                    a.click();

                    // Chrome requires the timeout
                    await delay(100);
                    a.remove();       
                }
            }
```

I got this example in this site: [multi-downloads](https://sindresorhus.com/multi-download/)

Comment: your code is not really the same is it ... in the code you linked to, there's an ever increasing delay between each download (though, that code looks wrong if you ask me, the delay is 0 second before the first download starts, THEN 1 second between 1st and 2nd download, THEN 2 seconds between the 2nd and 3rd download ... etc)

Comment: I try to implement this delay between each download but this doesn't work too.

Comment: I tested it sometimes in 2 situations: 3 images and 2 images to be downloaded. In 3 images situation, I notice that it download only the first and last image, after some clicks, it download the 3 images. If I click the download button without any delay this works but when I click and take 1 second, for example, don't work